# Does laravel custom service provider boot method runs periodically? (Laravel 6)

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-6

I implemented a custom service provider called PermissionServiceProvider, while debugging an issue I found that the boot method is calling periodically. In our testing server it is invoking every minute, whereas in our production server it seems invoking every seconds (invoking faster than the testing server )

[image]

Is it normal that service provider boot method is invoking periodically? What controls the periodicity that makes the difference in test and production server?

Attached production log snippet:
[image]

Comment: Do you know what a Service Provider is? There is no such thing as periodic invoke. If Service Provider is booting, you probably are doing something that requires a new app instance, therefore provider is booted. https://laravel.com/docs/9.x/providers

Comment: How can I validate a new app instance creating every time. From my side I just created the  permission service provider and it is working fine. However I just want to know why is it booting frequently. How can I check what cause it to boot. BTW, I am using laravel forge and deploy in AWS

Comment: I think this is because you start some worker who bootsrap application every minute

Comment: Your registered gate intercepts and allows or denies your methods. You probably have a Job running which is trying to do, or in fact doing something catched by the gate. Also verify if you are receiving any callback from 3th party services such as status checker. I think you can debug incoming request by logging `request()` or `$this->app->request` within your provider.

Comment: Are you just getting more requests on your production server vs test server?